# Is $f$ non-negative a.e. if its primitive is non-decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgue integrable.

Clearly, if $f$ is non-negative then
$$
g:[a,b]\ni x\mapsto\int_a^x f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\in\mathbb{R}
$$
is non-decreasing since for $x<y$ it holds
$$
g(y)-g(x)
=\int_a^y f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t-\int_a^x f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t
=\int_x^y f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\ge 0\text{.}
$$

How can I show that $f$ is non-negative almost everywhere if $g$ is non-decreasing?

I would suppose that $f$ is negative on a set $A\subseteq[a,b]$ of positive measure. Then there exists a compact set $B\subseteq A$ of positive measure and it holds
$$
\int_B f(t)\,\mathrm{d}x<0\text{.}
$$
Does $B$ contain a non-empty interval?

Comment: A Cantor set of positive measure does not contain a non-empty interval, and every interval contains such Cantor sets.

Comment: @Brian Thank you. So which is the way to go?

Comment: Another approach would use the Lebesgue density theorem.

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you for your hint. It would be interesting to see another proof. For the moment, since I am not familiar with the density theorem I have to postpone going into the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the [monotone class theorem](https://planetmath.org/MonotoneClassTheorem).  Assume without loss of generality that $f$ is Borel measurable (since there is a Borel measurable function $\tilde{f}$ with $f = \tilde{f}$ a.e.).
Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the collection of all Borel subsets $E \subset [a,b]$ for which $\int_E f \ge 0$.  Then $\mathcal{M}$ is a monotone class (use the dominated convergence theorem).  Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the collection of all finite unions of half-open intervals $[c,d)$.  Then $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra, $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{M}$, and $\mathcal{A}$ generates the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.  By the monotone class theorem, $\mathcal{M}$ equals the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.  In particular, $\{f < 0\} \in \mathcal{M}$, from which it follows that $f \ge 0$ a.e.

See also [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16244/if-int-0x-f-dm-is-zero-everywhere-then-f-is-zero-almost-everywhere).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In spite of your very helpful references I do not understand every step. Unfortunately, my knowledge of measure theory is too limited. Does every $S\in\mathcal{M}$ of positive measure contain a non-empty interval? Otherwise, I feel completely lost with your last sentence. :-(

Comment: @precarious: No, not every $S \in \mathcal{M}$ of positive measure will contain an interval.  (Indeed, $\mathcal{M}$ turns out to contain every Borel set, and there are certainly Borel sets of positive measure containing no interval, as Brian Scott's comment indicates.)  In the last sentence, $\{f < 0\}$ is shorthand for $\{x : f(x) < 0\}$, and I am pointing out that the integral of $f$ over this set is nonnegative.  Since $f$ is *strictly* negative on this set, it must be that the set has measure zero.

Comment: @precarious: I've intentionally left some of the details in my answer for you to work out; it will be educational.

Comment: Oh yes, now I understand your argument. Thank you! I am convinced that it is a good idea for me to thoroughly work through measure theory including this example. For the moment, I am much deeper into it than I originally wanted to go. However, I am going to return when my schedule admits.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [Jonas' answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/100927/22492) to my related question

- [Is $f$ non-decreasing a.e. if its primitive is convex?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100848/is-f-non-decreasing-a-e-if-its-primitive-is-convex)

I did some research and can now come up with an alternative solution.

In the book *The Integrals of Lebesgue, Denjoy, Perron, and Henstock* by Russell A. Gordon, it is stated that:

> A non-decreasing function $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable almost everywhere and $g'$ is non-negative where it exists.

Since $f=g'$ almost everywhere, $f$ is non-negative almost everywhere.