# Is $f$ non-decreasing a.e. if its primitive is convex?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

The subsequent statement can be regarded as a follow-up to

- [If $\int_0^x f \ dm$ is zero everywhere then $f$ is zero almost everywhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16244/if-int-0x-f-dm-is-zero-everywhere-then-f-is-zero-almost-everywhere)
- [Is $f$ non-negative a.e. if its primitive is non-decreasing?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99110/is-f-non-negative-a-e-if-its-primitive-is-non-decreasing)

> Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgue integrable.
>   Furthemore, let
>   $$
> g:[a,b]\ni x\mapsto\int_a^x f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\in\mathbb{R}
> $$
>   be convex. Then $f$ is non-decreasing almost everywhere.

Let $a\le x_0<x_1<x_2\le b$. Since $f$ is convex, we have
$$
\frac{g(x_2)-g(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}-\frac{g(x_1)-g(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}\ge 0\text{.}
$$
This can be reduced to
$$
\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{f(t)}{x_2-x_1}\,\mathrm{d}t
\ge\int_{x_0}^{x_1} \frac{f(t)}{x_1-x_0}\,\mathrm{d}t\text{.}
$$
The last formula roughly shows that the 'average' $f$ on $[x_0,x_1]$ does not exceed the 'average' of $f$ on $[x_1,x_2]$. Do you know a rigorous argument showing that $f$ is non-decreasing a.e.?

Comment: What does "non-decreasing almost everywhere" even mean?

Comment: @TonyK It means that there exists a set $X\subseteq [a,b]$ of measure $b-a$ such that for all $x_0,x_1\in X$ with $x_0\le x_1$ it holds $f(x_0)\le f(x_1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard result about convex functions is that they have nondecreasing one-sided derivatives everywhere.  Since $g'(x)=f(x)$ almost everywhere, $f$ is equal almost everywhere to the nondecreasing right-hand derivative of $g$.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the kind of argument I was looking for. Can you recommend literature where I can find a deep treatment of convex functions?

Comment: @precarious: Try "Convex functions: constructions, characterizations and counterexamples" by Jonathan M. Borwein, Jon D. Vanderwerff. http://carma.newcastle.edu.au/ConvexFunctions/CF-CCC.pdf

Comment: @matt Thank you for your recommendation. I had a quick look at the table of contents and the first chapter. I am not sure whether this is what I am looking for. The book seems to cover quite general settings while I am focused on univariate functions given on finite intervals. Maybe, a survey article about this topic would fit my needs best.

Comment: @precarious: I don't know if it is deep, but there is a good summary (with proofs) of some basic properties of convex functions in one variable in section 7.6 of Wheeden and Zygmund's *Measure and integral*, starting on [page 118](http://books.google.com/books?id=YDkDmQ_hdmcC&lpg=PP1&dq=wheeden%20zygmund&pg=PA118#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: @Jonas: Thank you. This reference is similar to what I was looking for. In the meantime, I also found *[Convex Functions](http://books.google.de/books?id=cqyHkkCxVtcC)* by Roberts and Varberg. Maybe 'deep' was said too much. On the other hand, these results are striking even if they seem to be folklore.