# Lebesgue integral on every interval equal implies two functions must be equal?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Suppose I have two Lebesgue measurable functions $f,g : [0,1] \to \mathbb R_+$ with the following property: 
$$ \int_0^x f(y) dy = \int_0^x g(y) dy$$ for a.e. $x \in [0,1]$. Can I conclude that $f=g$ a.e. on $[0,1]$ from here?

More generally, if I have two random variables $x,y$ such that $\mathbb E[ x \vert x \le a] = \mathbb E[y \vert y \le a]$ for a.e. $a \in \mathbb R$, can we say that $x =y$ a.s.?

Comment: This is a nice corollary of the fact that if the integral of a function is zero a.e. then the function is identically zero a.e. Just consider the integral of the difference of the two functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\frac  1 x$ for $x >0$, $f(0)=0$ and $g=2f$. Then hypothesis is satisfied but $f \neq g$. (Both sides are $\infty$.)

However the conclusion is true if $f$ and $g$ are integrable. This is  a consequence of Lebsgue's Theorem.  Ref.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem

Comment: If g=2f, I don't see how their integral can be equal, plus their integral don't even exist if f(x)=1/x

Comment: In measure theory one is not afraid of $\infty$!. Both sides of the equation exist and the  value of either side is $\infty$.   @Jeanba

Comment: Ok thanks for the precision!

Comment: For the case that $f,g$ are integrable, one can also give a proof without using the Lebesgue differentation theorem. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16244/if-int-0x-f-dm-is-zero-everywhere-then-f-is-zero-almost-everywhere/3458702#3458702

Comment: Thanks everyone. Indeed, I missed integrability in the condition. The proof without the Lebesgue differentiation theorem is quite nice too.