# A function which integrates to 0 over any set of measure 1

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Problem:

> $f$ is integrable on $[0,2]$, for any measurable set $E \subseteq [0,2]$, when $m(E) = 1$, $\int_E fdm = 0$ prove $f = 0$ $a.e.$ on $[0,2]$

I think the following theorem might be of help, but I'm not sure.

**Theorem.** If $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and $\int_a^x f(t)dt = 0$ $\forall x \in [a,b]$, then $f = 0$ $a.e.$ on $[a,b]$.

The proof is in this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16244/if-int-0x-f-dm-is-zero-everywhere-then-f-is-zero-almost-everywhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E_- = \{f < 0\}$ and $E_+ = \{f > 0\}$ and $A = [0,2] \setminus E_- \setminus E_+ = \{f = 0\}$. Suppose that $m(E_-) \geq 1$ or $m(E_+) \geq 1$. In either case we get a contradiction when integrating over the larger set. Thus $m(E_-),m(E_+) < 1$. Now we integrate over $E_- \cup A$ and $E_+ \cup A$ to find that in fact $m(E_-) = m(E_+) = 0$.

Comment: How to get the contradiction when integrating over the larger set?

Comment: Say $m(E_-) \geq 1$. Take a subset $E_-^* \subseteq E_-$ with $m(E_-^*) = 1$. Then the integral over $E_-^*$ is zero. But $f < 0$ on $E_-^*$, a contradiction.

Comment: I see. But can we always find a subset $E_-^*$ $\subseteq$ $E_-$ with measure 1?