# Proving that $\int_a^b g=0$ implies $g=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

Let $I\subset \Bbb R$ be an interval and let $g\in L^1(I)$ integrable over $I$ such that
$$\int_a^b g(x) dx=0\qquad \forall\,\, a,b\in I. $$

I would like to prove that $g=0$ a.e. without using density argument. My idea is to consider the set
$$A=\{x\in I\,:\, |g(x)|>0\}= \bigcup_{n\geq1} A_n $$
where
$$A_n=\{x\in I\,:\, |g(x)|>\frac{1}{n}\}.$$

How to show that $|A_n|=0$, i.e., $A_n$ is of measure zero?

In this way we can conclude that $|A|=0$ and hence $g=0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: One strategy is to se how that the subsets of $[a,b]$ over which the integral is $0$ forms a Dynkin system. The conclusion follows by Dynkin’s  monotone theorem

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/16244/42969